# Pulling all numbers from a quadratic equation using RE

Tags: python, regex, quadratic

I have the below quadratic equation from which i'm looking to pull the constants into a tuple to find the factors.

`3*(x**2)+5*x+6` - (I also don't want to pull the power 2).

I tried the below expressions. Most of them seem to be returning `None`

```
re.search('(\d*),(\d*),(\d*)','3*(x**2)+5*x+6').groups() - returns None

re.findall('([0-9]+.*)+([0-9]+.*)+([0-9]+.*)','3*(x**2)+5*x+6') - returns None

re.split('\D','3*(x**2)+5*x+6') - this is the closest i got - returns - ['3', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '5', '', '', '6']
```

Any ideas? I would prefer to use `re` as opposed to any other module.

Comment: whats your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the constants you can simply use a [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\*\*)\d',s)
['3', '5', '6']
```

`r'(?<!\*\*)\d'` will match any number that not preceding with double `*` character.